# 2D interpolation with logspaced points?

Tags: scipy, interpolation

I would like to interpolate a 2d function from values in array of size NxN. Unfortunately scipy' 2dinterpolation returns following error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Even for the simplified example listed below:

```
import scipy as S
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

def f(x,y):
MaxSum = 8
xTmp   = y/x # trad = y
z      = 0.0 

for n in range(1,MaxSum):
    z    =  z + ( ( S.exp((-1.0*n)*(1.0/y) ) - (1.0/x) ) / (n*x + y) )
return z

f_vec = S.vectorize(f)

N = 128

x = S.logspace(3,8,N) # Note that that I have to use log space for one argument!
                      # I suspect that this is an origin of the problem. 
y = S.linspace(3000,25000,N)

i, j = S.meshgrid(x, y)

z = f_vec(i,j)

plt.figure()
plt.grid(True)
plt.contourf(z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

# Interpolation

f_interpolated = interp2d(x, y, z) # error here 
x_new = S.logspace(3,8,3*N)
y_new = S.linspace(3000,25000,3*N)
z_iterpolated = f_interpolated(x_new, y_new)

plt.figure()
plt.grid(True)
plt.contourf(z_iterpolated)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Any ideas how could I debug or how could I interpolate it (I would like to stick with 2d linear interpolation since this scipy script is just a prototype for further implementation in Fortran where performance will be crucial issue)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whenever you can try to provide SSCCE , http://www.sscce.org/ and a little bit more  verbose description of the problem than `method failed`. Right now we don't know how `F` works and what is the value of `N`.

Comment: Works for me (OSX 10.8.5, Python 2.7.5, numpy 1.7.1, scipy 0.12.0, matplotlib 1.3.0). Which line exactly causes the segfault for you?

Comment: Error is from the call of interp2d function. The error is a one thing, but what about correctness of the results. I wonder if the fact that I am using scipy.logspace may affects final solution. Are the equally distanced nodes the requirements for 2d interpolation ?